# My player keeps respawning until my game crashes

Tags: game-development, godot, gdscript

i'm making an animation for my player. I am firstly trying to make the player, when died, to make a clone of itself. Well... when I touch a spike or something, the player starts making infinite clones of itself, and the game just crashes. here are 2 codes where the problem could be.

1. The "Base level" script:

---

```
extends Node

signal coin_total_changed

export(PackedScene) var levelCompleteScene

var playerScene = preload("res://scenes/Player.tscn")
var spawnPosition = Vector2.ZERO
var currentPlayerNode = null
var totalCoins = 30
var collectedCoins = 0

func _ready():
    spawnPosition = $PlayerRoot/Player.global_position
    register_player($PlayerRoot/Player)
    
    coin_total_changed(get_tree().get_nodes_in_group("coin").size())
    
# warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
    $Flag.connect("player_won", self, "on_player_won")
    
    
func coin_collected():
    collectedCoins += 1
    print(totalCoins, " - ", collectedCoins)
    emit_signal("coin_total_changed", totalCoins, collectedCoins)
    
func coin_total_changed(newTotal):
    totalCoins = newTotal
    emit_signal("coin_total_changed", totalCoins, collectedCoins)

func register_player(player):
    currentPlayerNode = player
    player.connect("died", self, "on_player_died", [], CONNECT_DEFERRED)

func create_player():
    var playerInstance = playerScene.instance()
    $PlayerRoot.add_child(playerInstance)
    playerInstance.global_position = spawnPosition
    register_player(playerInstance)

func on_player_died():
    currentPlayerNode.queue_free()
    
    var timer = get_tree().create_timer(1)
    yield(timer, "timeout")
    create_player()
    
func on_player_won():
    var levelComplete = levelCompleteScene.instance()
    add_child(levelComplete)
```

---

2. The "Player" script:

---

```
extends KinematicBody2D

#Variables and that stuff
signal died

var playerDeathScene = preload("res://Scenes/PlayerDeath.tscn")

enum State { NORMAL, DASHING }

export(int, LAYERS_2D_PHYSICS) var dashHazardMask

var gravity = 1000
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var maxHorizontalSpeed = 140
var maxDashSpeed = 500
var minDashSpeed = 200
var horizontalAcceleration = 2000
var jumpSpeed = 320
var jumpTerminationMultiplier = 4
var hasDoubleJump = false
var hasDash = false
var currentState = State.NORMAL
var isStateNew = true

var defaultHazardMask = 0

#All the other code things

func _ready():
# warning-ignore:return_value_discarded
    $HazardArea.connect("area_entered", self, "on_hazard_area_entered")
    defaultHazardMask = $HazardArea.collision_mask

func _process(delta):
    match currentState:
        State.NORMAL:
            process_normal(delta)
        State.DASHING:
            process_dash(delta)
    isStateNew = false
func change_state(newState):
    currentState = newState
    isStateNew = true

func process_normal(delta):
    if(isStateNew):
        $HazardArea.collision_mask = defaultHazardMask 
    var moveVector = Vector2.ZERO
    moveVector.x = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    moveVector.y = -1 if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") else 0
    velocity.x += moveVector.x * horizontalAcceleration * delta
    if (moveVector.x == 0):
        velocity.x = lerp(0, velocity.x, pow(2, -5))
        
    velocity.x = clamp(velocity.x,  -maxHorizontalSpeed, maxHorizontalSpeed)
    
    if (moveVector.y < 0 && (is_on_floor() || $CoyoteTimer.is_stopped() || hasDoubleJump)):
        velocity.y = moveVector.y * jumpSpeed
        if(!is_on_floor() && $CoyoteTimer.is_stopped()):
            hasDoubleJump = false
        $CoyoteTimer.stop()
        
    if(moveVector.y < 0 && !Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump")):
        velocity.x = gravity * jumpTerminationMultiplier * delta
    else:
        velocity.y += gravity * delta

    var wasOnFloor = is_on_floor()
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)

    if(wasOnFloor && !is_on_floor()):
        $CoyoteTimer.start()

    if(is_on_floor()):
        hasDoubleJump = true
        hasDash = true

    if(hasDash && Input.is_action_just_pressed("dash")):
        call_deferred("change_state", State.DASHING)
        hasDash = false

    update_animation()
    
func process_dash(delta):
    if(isStateNew):
        $"/root/Helpers".apply_camera_shake(1)
        $DashArea/CollisionShape2D.disabled = false
        $AnimatedSprite.play("Dash")
        $HazardArea.collision_mask = dashHazardMask
        var moveVector = get_movement_vector()
# warning-ignore:unused_variable
        var VelocityMod = 1
        if(moveVector.x != 0):
            VelocityMod = sign(moveVector.x)
        else:
            VelocityMod = 1 if $AnimatedSprite.flip_h else -1
        velocity = Vector2(maxDashSpeed * VelocityMod, 0)
    
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector2.UP)
    velocity.x = lerp(0, velocity.x, pow(2, -10 * delta))
    
    if(velocity.y < minDashSpeed): 
        call_deferred("change_state", State.NORMAL)
    
func get_movement_vector():
    var moveVector = Vector2.ZERO
    moveVector.x = Input.get_action_strength("move_right") - Input.get_action_strength("move_left")
    moveVector.y = -1 if Input.is_action_just_pressed("jump") else 0
    return moveVector

func update_animation():
    var moveVec = get_movement_vector()
    if(!is_on_floor()):
        $AnimatedSprite.play("Jump")
    elif(moveVec.x != 0):
        $AnimatedSprite.play("Run")      
    else:
        $AnimatedSprite.play("Idle")

    $AnimatedSprite.flip_h = true if moveVec.x > 0 else false

func kill():
    var playerDeathInstance = playerDeathScene.instance()
    get_parent().add_child_below_node(self, playerDeathInstance)
    playerDeathInstance.global_position = global_position
    playerDeathInstance.velocity = velocity
    emit_signal("died")

func on_hazard_area_entered(_area2d):
    $"/root/Helpers".apply_camera_shake(1)
    call_deferred("kill")
```

---

Have a great day!

Comment: Create a breakpoint on the first line inside of the `create_player()` function and view the stack trace in the [debugger panel](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/debug/debugger_panel.html) to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Does currentState change, when you die? Maybe the area triggered is somehow triggered more than once, because the character still moves slightly?